# node: relocation error: node: symbol alueEEE, version GLIBC_2.4 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

Tags: node.js, linux

Running a  similar  issue as described in [Cannot find /lib/libc.so.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964880/cannot-find-lib-libc-so-6?fbclid=IwAR1Kxcynuby-PerPyhuw6kJO-RrEj96496ox5yTtNu7GXrXPaazjEChb1LI#1966981)

[image: issue]

> try the -sysroot flag to g++/ld. Point it to $SYSROOT as defined in your Makefile.

but as a newbie, i dont even know what exactly is expected from me or what exactly do i have to type?

i tried , $SYSROOT,--sysroot ,--sysroot=/rootfs/prefix
im clueless , what exactly  is happening

i am trying to run nodejs  and install opencv4nodejs there
but not able to  do so.
do you think having nodemon,or  installing opencv with  npm , and also   opencv 3.3  .  or any launcher  script to run a python script everytime

`cd
cd folder
sudo  file_name.py
cd`

what is the issue here please let me know???

currently i cant even open nodejs in my raspberry pi.

Btw, my gcc/g++ is 6.3

Comment: Where was node built? It sounds like it was built linking to a newer version of libc than what is currently on your pi. Without more of the information on how node was built, it's difficult to suggest the right fix for this.

Comment: hi, it was build in the raspberry itself. i followed the instructions in https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_raspberrypi.asp sorry for the late response.

Comment: If you followed those instructions, you downloaded nodejs, you didn't build it locally. The error indicates that libc.so.6 does not expose the symbol alueEEE bound to GLIBC api 2.4. It means something incompatible has creeped into your system. use `type -p node` to determine where node is coming form - if it's the package, then it should say `/usr/bin/node`. If it doesn't then something is your path is causing the problem. There could be something like the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` interfering as well.

Comment: You didn't mention what version of node you installed, what the results of `dpkg -V nodejs` show (i.e. verify that nodejs installed correctly).